Error: Target File "build" Not Found When Running flutter run build apk --release
flutter run build apk --release
However, I am encountering the following error:
Target file "build" not found.
I expected the APK to be built, but instead, the command fails.
Here are the details of my environment:
Flutter version:  3.24.1
Dart version:Dart 3.5.1
OS: Windows 11
I have tried running flutter clean and flutter pub get before running the command again, but the issue persists.
Am I using the wrong command or missing a configuration step? Any help would be appreciated.

You can simply use flutter build apk
also check if you have internet added on your AndroidManifest file
Open the file "android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" and add the proper user-permission:
<manifest> 
...
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
...
</manifest>


i already added permissions

Long story short, yes, you are using wrong command :) For your use case it is flutter build apk. No need for run since it's another command and no need for --release since it's default mode when building apk.
Good luck!

Execution failed for task ':connectivity:verifyReleaseResources'. this comming

That's another error, you probably should search for existing questions for this matter, or file a new one with logs and all that stuff.

use flutter build apk --release don't use as flutter run build apk --release won't work.
now try to build apk
